# Create a regex range with two decimal number as optional number

Tags: regex

I have a scenario where I need to validate a number that is less than 6000.00
It should accept;
0.0, 
001.00, 
01 , 
5999.99, 
6000.00
All these should match.
6000.01 should not match.

Comment: Do you really want to support zeroes before the whole number like this `001.00`? I don't think you should. In case you really want to support, then are `0000001.00` and `00000021` and similar numbers valid too? And do you want to support numbers without whole number being present? Like `.1` or `.01` too?

Comment: Thats the requirement sir. 0001.00 is valid, before decimal number there can be number ranging from 1 to 4

Comment: Ok Anirudh, if that's the requirement then that's fine. You can use this regex `^0*(?:(?:(?:[0-5]\d{3}|\d{0,3})(?:\.\d{1,2})?)|6000(?:\.0{1,2})?)$`. Check this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Falkv4/1/) Let me know if this covers all cases for you.